# How to convert list of strings to list of integers?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to request a list of numbers (ex: "1 2 3 4 5 6") and output a list of integers (ex: "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]"). I have come up with the following code:

```
IO.gets ("Enter a list: ")
|> String.trim
|> String.split
|> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
```

This will not compile and gives me the following error:

```
== Compilation error in file test.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("Enter")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    test.ex:4: (file)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in 
Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I have run this code one line at a time through iex using the result of each function as an input to the next and achieve the correctly formatted list BUT when I put it all together in a file and run it, it won't even compile...

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is a space between `IO.gets` and the opening parenthesis. This would work:

```rb
IO.gets("Enter a list: ")
|> String.trim
|> String.split
|> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
```

Operator precedence matters:

```rb
#  3           1
IO.inspect (IO.inspect(42, label: "foo"))
#     2 
|> IO.inspect(label: "bar")

foo: 42
bar: 42
42
```

Let’s see what happened here: I placed numbers denoting the order of execution. The first executed is "foo", *then "bar"*, and only then the firstly placed inspect. That happens because Elixir allows (although discourages) function calls without parentheses, and pipe `|>` takes a precedence over the function call.

Comment: @Aetherus that’s the answer by all means, isn’t it?

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I totally get it now. I do have one more issue though. When entering my list, it now outputs a blank list "[ ]"... So funny because it works when I do it line by line in iex still. Any idea on that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about and I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Please post another question with a detailed explanation of the issue if still in doubt.